# Block access to column without changing query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, user-permissions

I have a Microsoft SQL Server with data that needs to be protected (certain sensitive columns of some tables) and an application that queries that database like this:

```
SELECT BoringColumn, SensitiveColumn FROM Table
```

I have the following restrictions:

1. I have multiple users (3-4) each with different columns visible or not.
   In this example SensitiveColumn should not be accessible.
2. I can **not** directly update the queries that the application sends

What did I try already:

I tried to use [SQL Servers Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2017) feature. However it's not granular enough, you can just turn it on or off per user but not just for some columns. And its can leak data in queries, the link above explains that as well.

I know I can just deny the user `SELECT` on `Table.SensitiveColumn`.
However then any existing query asking for the table just breaks with permission errors.

What other options do I have left?

Ideally I would like something that replaces the query on the serverside and executes something like this:

```
SELECT BoringColumn, 'N/A' as SensitiveColumn FROM Table
```

Comment: "I can not directly update the queries that the application sends". Can you control the database structure? I mean, rename objects, alter tables, stuff like that

Comment: Good question, yes I can do that.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask the application to do there selects agains views instead. Then it will be easier for you to maintain the security issues

Comment: Yeah modifying the application would be the easiest approach, Its just not an option since this application is shared and really difficult to modify.

Comment: It's a bit hooky, but could you change the name of the table, add a view called the name of the table and add an instead of trigger on the view. Not nice I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a possible solution:
Change the table structure - Rename the SensitiveColumn to a different name, and add a computed column with the old name of the SensitiveColumn, that will show results based on [`current_user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest
(
    boringColumn int,
    SensitiveBase varchar(10), -- no user should have direct access to this column!
    SensitiveColumn as 
        case current_user 
            when 'Trusted login' then SensitiveBase
            else 'N/A' 
        end
)
```

The one thing I'm not sure about is if you can deny access to the `SensitiveBase` column but grant it to the `SensitiveColumn`.
I'll leave you to test it yourself.
If that can't be done, you can simply grant select permissions on the `SensitiveBase` column only to `trusted login` and deny them for everyone else.

Comment: That is actually a nice idea. I could also set the SensitiveBase column to HIDDEN so that even SELECT * FROM tblTest would work.

Comment: I will try in the next days and come back to you!

Comment: If you deny permission to sensitivebase, select * will fail with the SELECT permission was denied on column 'sensitivebase'. You could take the approach above and then mask sensitivebase

Comment: @Bluuu `hidden` is only applicable to system generated columns.

Comment: @SteveFord yes, that's correct. To overcome this another option would be to rename the table, and create a view containing only the relevant columns with the same name as the old table name - though it might introduce other problems (such as compatibility with already existing naming conventions, updatablility of the view (that can be solved using `instead of` triggers, but might require a lot of code)

Comment: @ZoharPeled man, the `hidden` would have made this the perfect solution. Its still a good start without working `SELECT *` though.

Comment: Well, as I wrote to SteveFord, another possible solution would be to rename the table and create a view with only the relevant columns. this way, you can deny permissions on the entire table and only grant permissions on the view, but as I said, it might come with a price tag.